# export: Command not found raised by linux source command

Tags: linux, environment-variables

after I installed Anaconda package on the server, I'm then trying `source ~/.bashrc` to set env variable, but it raise an error of `export: Command not found`, my `.bashrc` file is like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin:$PATH"
```

can anyone help? thanks very much!

Comment: Are you sure your login shell is `bash`? What does `echo $SHELL` say?

Comment: the `echo $SHELL` command says  `/usr/local/bin/tcsh` ,what should I do then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using `tcsh`, not `bash`, you should edit your `.cshrc` and add the line:

```
set path = ( /projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin $path )
```

Then use `source .cshrc`.

Comment: thank you, I run `set path = ( /projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin $path )` ,and then run `source .cshrc` , then I tried `conda`, but it still raise `conda: command not found`

Comment: If you list that directory do you see the the `conda` command there?

Comment: yes, actually when I `cd` to `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin`, I can run `conda` command there correctly

Comment: I tried `rehash` command, then ran `set path = ( /projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin $path )` and `source ~/.cshrc` again, then try `conda` ,but it still raise `conda: command not found`

Comment: You have to run `rehash` *after* you set path.

Comment: I tried `set path = ( /projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin $path )` , then `rehash` ,then `source ~/.cshrc` ,but it still does not work, when I open the `cshrc` file with `vim ~/.cshrc` ,I can't find the `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin` in it, so is there some problem with the `cshrc` file ? I'm running on remote server using `SSH`

Comment: You edited the file to add the line, but then when you opened it again your couldn't find it? Are you sure you saved before exiting `vim` the first time?

Comment: it works now, instead of using `set path = ( /projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin $path )` I manually add `/projdata3/info_fil/wangtao/conda/bin` to `PATH` variable in `.cshrc` file, then `source ~/.cshrc`, then I can access `conda` command correctly

Comment: `tcsh` automatically maps the `path` array to the `PATH` environment variable. I'm not sure why only one of them works for you.

Answer (score 4):

If your shell is `.csh` please use `setenv` to export a variable which in bash you would normally do with `export`

In `bash`, `export My_VARIABLE=/some/location/or/.something/`

In `csh` shell, it would be `setenv My_VARIABLE /some/location/or/.something/`

Answer (score 2):

If `echo $SHELL` command is giving `/usr/local/bin/tcsh` then it means you are working in csh shell.

In csh shell, if you want to set environment variables, the syntax goes like this

```
setenv <variable_name> <variable_value>
```

Here is the useful csh commands [link](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/c_shell_cmds.htm) for reference

If you want to enter bash shell from csh shell, enter command `bash`

Then this command will work: `export <variable_name>=<variable_value>`